# Core Data: Re-assign parent entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Using Core Data, what's the proper way to re-assign the parent entity?

I have a `Car` entities that has one-to-many relationship with wheels and is cascaded delete (if the car is deleted, all its wheels are also deleted).  Each wheel can only have one `Car` parent. How do I re-assign the wheel to a different Car?

For example:
Car-A has Wheel1, Wheel2, Wheel3, Wheel4 as its children.
I want to move Wheel1, Wheel2, Wheel3, Wheel4 to a new parent called Car-B.

Here's what I've done:

```
for (Wheel *wheel in carA.wheels) {
   wheel.car = carB;
}
```

However, the above throws error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <_NSFaultingMutableSet: 0x7fe0537dd2b0> was mutated while being enumerated.'
```

Besides the error being thrown, I also feel simply re-assign the parent entity as above is not the proper way.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are mutating the set directly within the `for`-loop which leads to the error. Assuming, the set is a `NSMutableSet`, the proper way to do this would be:

```
NSArray* wheels = [carA.wheels allObjects];
for (NSManagedObject* wheel in wheels)
{
    [carA removeObject:wheel]
    [carB addObject:wheel]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, I've forgotten about those two convenient methods.

Comment: This method doesn't seem to work on iCloud ubiquitous persistent store. I tried this on core data and it worked, but it doesn't on ubiquitous. Any idea why?

Comment: Is there some error you get, or does it simply not work?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mutate a collection that you are enumerating. If you think about it, it is quite logical that this has to lead to problems.

The solution is to separate the items first.

```
NSSet *wheels = carA.wheels
carA.wheels = nil;
for (Wheel *wheel in wheels) {
  wheel.car = carB;
}
```